# Receiving bound event from component inside component or mdDialog

Tags: angularjs, callback, angular-material, angular-components

With Angular 1.5 and Material Design, I have created a component that represents a panel for creating a foobar, with a "cancel" button. Obviously the panel doesn't know if it's in a dialog or not, so the "cancel" button merely invokes a callback. Specifically, the "cancel" button calls the `cancel()` method of the controller, which then tries to invoke the `oncancel()` callback:

```
angular.module("NewFooBarPanel", [])
    .component("newFoobarPanel", {
        templateUrl: "newfoobar-template.html",
        bindings: {
            onCancel: "&"
        },
        controller: function() {
            var controller = this;

            controller.cancel = function() {
                controller.clearForm();
                controller.onCancel({});
            }
```

In the enclosing component, I bring up an mdDialog when a FAB is clicked; the dialog contains the newFoobarPanel:

```
angular.module("FoobarList", ["NewFooBarPanel"])
    .component("foobarList", {
        templateUrl: "foobarlist-template.html",
        controller: function($mdDialog) {

            this.addFoobar = function(ev) {

                $mdDialog.show({
                        template: "<md-dialog aria-label='Add Foobar'><new-foobar-panel on-cancel='alert(\"need to cancel\")'></new-foobar-panel></md-dialog>",
                        targetEvent: ev,
                        clickOutsideToClose: true,
                        fullscreen: true
                    });
```

When I click the cancel button, the form is cleared so I know that the newFoobarPanel controller's `cancel()` method is being called. But I don't see an alert dialog, so for some reason the `on-cancel` callback in `<new-foobar-panel on-cancel='alert(\"need to cancel\")'></new-foobar-panel>` doesn't seem to be getting called.

This is complicated stuff (even though it is a simple, straightforward use case), with a component inside of a dialog inside of a component. I seem to have narrowed down the problem to the invocation of the callback. Where did I go wrong?

So I decided to take mdDialog out of the picture altogether. Now I simply embed the newFoobarPanel directly in the foobarList component:

```
<new-foobar-panel on-cancel='alert("need to cancel")'></new-foobar-panel>
```

Now this is just a component inside a component, yet I'm still not seeing an alert dialog. Why isn't the callback getting invoked?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was not that the callback was not being invoked. The problem was how to recognize it. Apparently `alert()` does not work in this context.

So I had to add a controller to the mdDialog and and add a method to `$scope` to receive the callback:

```
                $mdDialog.show({
                        controller: function($scope, $log) {
                          $scope.notify=function() {
                            $log.debug("need to cancel");
                          }
                        },
                        template: "<md-dialog aria-label='Add Foobar'><new-foobar-panel on-cancel='notify()'></new-foobar-panel></md-dialog>",
                        targetEvent: ev,
                        clickOutsideToClose: true,
                        fullscreen: true
                    });
```

Now the dialog controller logs a message when the embedded component invokes the callback! Great!

If there is a better way to add controller methods here (can I rely on `this`?) instead of injecting `$scope`, let me know.

(Now I need to figure out how to close the mdDialog from its controller, but that's a separate issue.)